# Change font in JavaFx using CSS

Tags: css, javafx, fonts

I know this topic has been discussed and I have googled and looked at previous question but none of their solutions seemed to help, I even looked at this [example](https://github.com/TheItachiUchiha/FontLoad), infact am using the code from the example, the code runs correctly if i import it, when I try it in my project if fails to change the font. So I have this folder [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3X3m9.png), The `fonts` folder is in the resource folder and the code that is to change the font is

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'GoodDog';
src: url('fonts/GoodDog.otf');
}

.numberSpinner{

-fx-padding: 0.5em 0.0em 0.5em 0.0em;
-fx-font-family: 'GoodDog';
-fx-font-size: 50;
-fx-text-fill: black;
}
```

Then call `numberSpinner` in my `FXML` like

```
 <Label fx:id="lblNumber" prefHeight="106.0" prefWidth="708.0" styleClass="numberSpinner" text="097116550800000"/>
```

Then finally add the `css` to the scene like

```
 scene.getStylesheets().add(MainFX.class.getResource("/resources/css/defaultFxCss.css").toExternalForm());
```

note that the stylesheet is added successfully as other components change according to it except the font for `numberSpinner`

So where am i going wrong?

Comment: try absolute path: `src: url('/resources/fonts/GoodDog.otf');`